# How to show total number of hours from the database input in php

Tags: time

How do I sum the hours and minutes and output the total time taken.

For eg:
Data saved in database

```
1.05
1.15
1.45
1.30
```

I need to display total number as `5.35`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Doesn't your database have a native date/time type to work with?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using a proper DateTime[Span] type in your database, but if the database is beyond your control, you need to do the following:

1. Split each number into hours and minutes (or minutes and seconds).

```python
    hours = int(time);
    mins = (time - hours) * 100;
```

2. Convert to a total number of minutes:

```python
    totalMins = hours * 60 + mins;
```

3. Add up all the `totalMins`.
4. Convert back to hours and minutes:

```python
    newHours = int(newTotalMinutes/60);
    newMins = newTotalMinutes % 60;
```

5. Stick the two parts back together:

```python
    newTime = newHours + newMins / 100.0
```

So (you didn't tag with a language, so I'll use python, as it's pretty good as pseudocode):

```python
total = 0
for time in [1.05, 1.15, 1.45, 1.30]:
    hours = int(time)
    mins = (time - hours)*100
    total += hours*60 + mins

totalTime = total/60 + (total%60)/100.0
print("Total Time is", totalTime)
```